# Dead lock on the same key between two equal INSERT queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have an INSERT query:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.AnotherTable    
(CorrespondenceRecordKey,
FeedbackFileDataKey,
FeedbackRecordStatusCode,
RecordLevelErrorCode,   
ActivityPeriodKey,
SwiftNessHandlerId,                 
LastProcessStatusCode,  
LastProcessStatusDate,  
RecordGUID, 
IsLastAnswer,   
GeneralFileDataXMLKey,  
RowReference)

OUTPUT

INSERTED.RecordKey,
INSERTED.CorrespondenceRecordKey,
INSERTED.FeedbackFileDataKey,
INSERTED.FeedbackRecordStatusCode,
INSERTED.RecordLevelErrorCode,
INSERTED.ActivityPeriodKey,
INSERTED.CorrespondenceCRMID,
INSERTED.CorrespondenceSyncKey,
INSERTED.SwiftNessHandlerId,
INSERTED.LastProcessStatusCode,
INSERTED.LastProcessStatusDate,
INSERTED.RecordGUID,
INSERTED.IsLastAnswer,
INSERTED.GeneralFileDataXMLKey,
INSERTED.RowReference 

INTO #Temp3

SELECT

NRFC.RecordKey AS CorrespondenceRecordKey,
SomeTable.RecordKey AS FeedbackFileDataKey,
fid.FeedbackRecordStatusCode,
fid.RecordLevelErrorCode,
fid.ActivityPeriodKey,
fid.SwiftNessHandlerId,
fid.LastProcessStatusCode,
fid.LastProcessStatusDate,
fid.RecordGUID,
fid.IsLastAnswer,
fid.GeneralFileDataXMLKey,
fid.RowReference

FROM #Temp1 fid
INNER JOIN #Temp2 NRFC 
    ON NRFC.RecordGUID = fid.CorrespondenceRecordGUID
INNER JOIN dbo.SomeTable 
    ON SomeTable.RecordGUID = fid.FeedbackFileDataGUID;
```

The `INSERT` is the part of hard working procedure. The procedure works in parallel threads.

We have `CLUSTERED INDEX` on  `SomeTable(RecordKey)` and `NONCLUSTERED` on `SomeTable.RecordGUID`. The execution plan shows usage of `NONCLUSTERED INDEX`.

At least we got `DEAD LOCK` on `NONCLUSTERED INDEX` that occurs between two equal `INSERTS`. The inserts asks S-type of lock and X-type of lock on the `NONCLUSTERED INDEX` and the questions are:

1. Why X-type lock occurs?
2. Why the DEAD LOCK occurs?
3. How can I fight it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the tags of your question to include related tags so more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. I also improved the formatting so that it improves readability  - please see [the editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on editing questions. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

An Xtype lock occurs any time SQL Server inserts/updates a row. A deadlock (very different then simple locking) occurs if process A has a lock on resource 1 and is waiting for resource 2 (in the context of a transaction) while process B has a lock on resource 2 while waiting for resource 1.

SQL Server will detect this and kill whatever process did the least amount of work and let the other one complete the transaction. The easiest way to fight it is to access the resources in the same order - this way which ever process gets resource 1 will prevent the other process from starting and the first resource will finish, release everything and the second process can then do what it has to do.

Comment: Thanks. But we are in another situation. There is nothing being inserted, updated or deleted from (into or in) the table that has been locked. Processes are in the same order more than that they are pretty identical :) I would understand if it could be shared lock because of INNER JOIN more than that let's say that the X-type lock will be understood (but it won't). I can't understand the dead lock...